# raid boot error

Tags: linux, raid, boot, raid1

in boot.log

```
/dev/md1: clean, 320806/58155008 files, 91390310/232603728 blocks
/dev/md0 was not cleanly unmounted, check forced.
/dev/md0: 32/24384 files (9.4% non-contiguous), 19957/97536 blocks
mountall: fsck /boot [484] terminated with status 1
init: ureadahead-other main process (881) terminated with status 4^M
```

And the server has died... How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you restarted the machine since you received this error?  fsck status 1 indicates that the filesystem in question had an error, but it was able to repair it.  Theoretically the machine should have continued booting afterwards.

Also, ureadhead-other errors in the init process can sometimes be caused by misspellings in the /etc/network/interfaces file.  If you have recently made changes to that file, you may want to use an ubuntu rescue CD to mount the filesystem and revert those changes or check for spelling mistakes therein.  This assumes you're using Ubuntu.